# Making a separation between lines in an environment with a tabular environmen

Tags: tables, environments

I'm trying to use awesome-cv (https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV). This is the code that I copied from the awesome-cv.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{5.5mm}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newenvironment{cvinterests}{%
    \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
    \vspace{-2mm}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ C{1cm} L{\textwidth - 1cm} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} }
}{%
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
}
\newcommand*{\cvhighlight}[1]{%
    $\bullet$ & #1\\
}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\begin{cvinterests}

\cvhighlight
    {Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe your activities, accomplishments, and successes.} 

\cvhighlight
    {Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe your activities, accomplishments, and successes.} 

\end{cvinterests}   

\end{document}
```

With the compilation, I see that the separation between items is the same as the line separation to make it hard to read.

[image]

Setting extrarowheight `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}` gives the separation between items, but I need to control the space between lines.

[image]

I tried `\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip}` in the `cvinterests` environment, but there is no change. 
How to give separation between lines in an environment with a tabular environment?

Comment: how about changing the lengths you've set? `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}` would do the trick. May not be what you are looking for, but it seems to work in this example.

Comment: @Runar Trollet: Thanks for the answer, but I revised my question as I also need to change the space between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the spacing between lines, you could use the `\linespread{factor}`-command. This should in most cases be kept the same throughout your document, so it is used mainly in the preamble. To use it anywhere else, use `\selectfont` after it. In the example below, the change is set locally for your environment only.

Changing the spacing between items(or rows here), could in your example be set  `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}` or you could use `\\[5ex]` in your `\cvhighlight`-macrodefiniton instead of just `\\`. I think the latter would be a better solution, which wouldn't effect anything else.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
% tables - Making a separation between items in an environment with a tabular environmen - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange
% Url: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326477/making-a-separation-between-items-in-an-environment-with-a-tabular-environmen
% Date: torsdag 25. august 2016 16.12.12


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{5.5mm}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newenvironment{cvinterests}{%
    \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
    \vspace{-2mm}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
        \linespread{1.2}\selectfont
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ C{1cm} L{\textwidth} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} }
}{%
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
}
\newcommand*{\cvhighlight}[1]{%
    $\bullet$ & #1\\% or use \\[5ex]
}

\begin{document}

\section{Text with normal spacing}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{cvinterests}

\cvhighlight{Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe your activities, accomplishments, and successes.}
\cvhighlight{Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe your activities, accomplishments, and successes.}
\cvhighlight{Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe your activities, accomplishments, and successes.}

\end{cvinterests}

\section{Spacing is still normal}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why using `tabular*` (with too wide columns, by the way).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\newcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{5.5mm}

\newenvironment{cvinterests}
 {%
  \begin{itemize}[
    leftmargin=*,
    topsep=\acvSectionContentTopSkip,
    itemsep=10pt,
  ]%
 }
 {%
  \end{itemize}
 }
\newcommand*{\cvhighlight}[1]{\item #1}

\begin{document}

\noindent Hello.

\begin{cvinterests}

\cvhighlight{Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can 
  sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe
  your activities, accomplishments, and successes.} 

\cvhighlight{Avoid the bland phrase responsibilities included. This can 
  sound like a dull job description. Instead, use bullets to describe
  your activities, accomplishments, and successes.} 

\end{cvinterests}

\noindent Hello.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just copied the code, so I'm not sure also. But what I notice is that the bullet point is in the middle of the row with tabular* environment.

Comment: @prosseek The vertically centered bullet is very dubious. I believe it  makes no sense, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: Also, the original code is `L{\textwidth - 1cm}`, but the (-1cm) becomes the part of output, so I removed them. I guess my removal of (-1cm) may make the table width too large.

Comment: @prosseek You need `\usepackage{calc}` for that syntax to work.